# SQL - Delete random rows where sum is equal to given number

Tags: sql

I want to get some random rows from the given table where the sum is 250(this can be changed). I don`t need to 100% accurate but can be approximate.
Like for 250 (1,5,7)

Note:- My table has huge data.

```
id | amount|
1  |   96 |
2  |   0.63 |
3  |   351.03 |
4  |   736| 
5  |   53 |
6  |   39 |
7  |   105 |
8  |   91 |
```

Comment: This is going to be super difficult. Can you please edit your question to give us a bit more information about why you want to find and then delete rows where the sum of the amount adds up to a value? And how many rows should add up to 250? or is it any number of rows? Like if 250 rows had a value of 1 would they fit the bill?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any specific numbers, you can return the closest sum using logic with joins.  For instance for 3 numbers -- as in your example:

```
select t1.*, t2.*, t3.*
from t t1 join
     t t2
     on t1.id < t2.id join
     t t3
     on t2.id < t3.id
order by abs(250 - (t1.amount + t2.amount + t3.amount))
fetch first 1 row only;
```

Note that `fetch first` is standard SQL.  Some databases spell it differently, for instance as `limit` or `select top`.